# packet colorization in Wireshark

Tags: wireshark, packet-capture

is there anyone who could sum up the packet colorization system in wireshark? My capture list is looking quite colourful, but I don't quite understand how the colorization scheme work.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some people, Wireshark colouring rules make it easier for "interesting" traffic to pop out, making troubleshooting issues a bit easier.

Head into View > Coloring Rules to see which rules are configured. Packets which match the display filters configured will be coloured accordingly.

For example, if you have a Wireshark capture of a connection to a website, a simple display filter of `http` will show you only HTTP packets. If you wanted to have those HTTP packets have a yellow background, you could add a Colouring Rule with the same `http` filter and a colour of your choice.

Any display filter that you can think of could be used as a colouring rule.